# Simple code methods (Intent, finish(), etc...) are not recognized

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I think it has something to do with gradle, but anyway the simple methods now do not work and aren't recognized by the system and it shows a red line under them, this picture shows it.(The picture is just to show the red line)[image: Picture]

The code at the top -

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class DriverLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText etDriverEmail, etDriverPassword;
    private Button btnDriverLogin, btnDriverRegistration;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;
```

Comment: "What do I need to do?" => You first need to ask a proper question. First of all, do not post images of code, but post it as text. Second, post also the error message (here: the compiler error). But you also should tell us, what you did to solve the problem yourself, and where you failed.

Comment: Sorry for missing some of the information, the picture is just to show the red line under the code :) Thanks for the comment really helped me <3

Comment: Just wondering, are you using a recent version of Android Studio? Did you consider creating this project with Kotlin. Also, have you tried Invalidate Caches & Restart?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing the correct imports. Also make sure your activity extends
the right class, E.g. Activity or AppCompatActivity

```java
import android.os.Bundle; //Make sure all imports are satisfied

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity{ //your activity implementation has to extend an activity class.
...
}
```

If a class is not imported (and you're using Android studio) you can always press CTRL + SPACE while having the cursor in the missing class/ method to import it.

BTW: The

```java
@Override
```

throws an error when the method does not override from its superclass. This is either because you forgot to extend (Base)Activity / AppCompatActivity, or those in turn where not imported at the top of your activity class.

Comment: I created a totally new project and I see the same, I think some files are missing.

Comment: Now that you've updated your answer i can see that you're using AppCompatActivity. Did you include that in your gradle build? it should be something like compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.X. more info can be found here :https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages